# Does this specific problem about lists have a well known algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Imagine a list l. I want to find all lists x where every element inside it is in l, repeated how many times necessary. x satisfies f(x) = true, where f is a function that only outputs true finitely many times. To not test every list, which is impossible, another condition exists: if f(x) = false, then f(X) = false, where X is an extension of x.

For example let l = [1,2,3].
I would do it manually like this: first we test the list []. If f([]) = false, we would be done because every other list is an extension of [], but lets assume f([]) = true. Then we test the lists [1] [2] [3]. Lets assume f([3]) = false. Now for lists of size 2 we have [1,1] [1,2] [1,3] [2,2] [2,3] [3,3], but every list with a 3 in it is an extension of [3] so they are all false. Lets also assume f([1,2]) = false. Then we are left with [1,1] [2,2]. For the next step the only lists remaining will be [1,1,1] [2,2,2] since any list with a 1 and a 2 is an extension of [1,2], and so on until we terminate.

Does this general problem have a name and if so an efficient algorithm to solve it? I would then manually modify it to suit my needs.

I don't see an obvious way to do this besides the clearly inefficient way of extending the current lists, removing duplicates, and applying f.

Comment: Your solution will be similar to performing a recursive traversal of a non-binary tree.